# How to ensure page is refreshed in single page app

Tags: html, aurelia, systemjs

I have a single page app written using Aurelia.  It works great.

However, when I roll out an update, it is sometimes difficult to get the browser to refresh the cached pages, and so it shows an older version.

Have tried, Refreshing the Browser, Control F5.

Have also put this in the heads of index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE">
```

But I don't think when system.js fetches individual components that the above would have any effect.

Comment: So is this a problem when you are developing everything or that a user will maybe "work" on a old version?

Comment: Only an issue for end user. But I found an answer and will post.

Answer (score 1):

After some more searching, I found [this](https://vadosware.io/2015/05/17/cache-busting-with-systemjsaurelia/) that explains how to cache-bust with SystemJs.

```
var systemLocate = System.locate;
      System.locate = function(load) {
        var System = this;
        return Promise.resolve(systemLocate.call(this, load)).then(function(address) {
          if(address.lastIndexOf("html.js") > -1) return address;
          if(address.lastIndexOf("css.js") > -1) return address;
          return address + System.cacheBust;
        });
      };
      System.cacheBust = '?bust=' + Date.now();

      System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
```